# How to vertically center content of Alert/DialogPane?

Tags: javafx

I created an `Alert` that is `undecorated` and I want the content to be centered in the alert. However, there seems to be some padding at the bottom that I can not get rid of.

Here is an MCVE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE);

        DialogPane pane = new DialogPane();
        HBox contentPane = new HBox(10);
        contentPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        contentPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Add progress indicator and label to contentPane
        contentPane.getChildren().addAll(
                new ProgressIndicator(ProgressIndicator.INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS) {{
                    setPrefSize(30, 30);
                }},
                new Label("Loading ...")
        );

        // Add border to demonstate the lower padding
        contentPane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");

        pane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        pane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");
        pane.setContent(contentPane);
        alert.setDialogPane(pane);

        alert.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        alert.showAndWait();

    }
}
```

The result is this window:

[image: Screenshot]

How do I create an `Alert` or `DialogPane` without that gap at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.layout.Border;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStroke;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderStrokeStyle;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderWidths;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

  private static Border createBorder(Paint stroke) {
    return new Border(new BorderStroke(stroke, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, 
                                       null, new BorderWidths(2)));
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ProgressIndicator indicator = new ProgressIndicator();
    indicator.setPrefSize(30, 30);

    Label label = new Label("Loading...");
    label.setMinWidth(Label.USE_PREF_SIZE);

    HBox content = new HBox(10, indicator, label);
    content.setBorder(createBorder(Color.BLUE));
    content.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    content.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE);
    alert.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    alert.getDialogPane().getStylesheets()
         .add(getClass().getResource("Main.css").toExternalForm());
    alert.getDialogPane().setPadding(new Insets(10));
    alert.getDialogPane().setContent(content);
    alert.getDialogPane().setBorder(createBorder(Color.RED));
    alert.show();
  }
}
```

Where this is `Main.css`:

```
.dialog-pane .button-bar .container {
  -fx-padding: 0px;
}

.dialog-pane:no-header .graphic-container {
  -fx-padding: 0px;
}
```

Resulted in the following:

[image: image of alert]

---

Some of the needed style-classes I got from [here (JavaFX CSS Reference)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#dialogpane). However, I mostly figured this out from looking at `modena.css` (where they have the styles for `dialog-pane`).

---

If you don't want to use external CSS you can replace `alert.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add(...)` with:

```
alert.getDialogPane().applyCss(); // Seems to stop the lookup calls
                                  // from returning null
alert.getDialogPane()
     .lookup(".button-bar")
     .lookup(".container")
     .setStyle("-fx-padding: 0px;");
alert.getDialogPane().lookup(".graphic-container").setStyle("-fx-padding: 0px;");
alert.show();
```

**Update following your comments.**

I initially tried this using Java 10.0.2 but I just tried using Java 8u181 and it still worked for me. I notice in your MCVE you are using a *new* `DialogPane` whereas I am using the `DialogPane` that initially comes with the `Alert`. Note that the `applyCss()` method will only work if the `Node` is a part of a `Scene`. Apparently the `DialogPane` is made part of a `Scene` as soon as it's part of the `Alert`. So one way you could avoid the `NullPointerException`s is to use the `DialogPane` that comes with the `Alert`, as I do.

If you still want to use your own `DialogPane` you just have to call `alert.setDialogPane` before calling `applyCss()`. Note that when I tried this, however, the call `lookup(".graphic-container")` still returned `null`. I guess that `Node` is only present on the original `DialogPane`. Removing that `lookup` call fixed it and the other `lookup` call (for `.button-bar > .container`) still worked as expected.

All this seems like implementation behavior that should not be relied upon but it works for me on both Java 8 and Java 10. I'd watch this code when changing Java versions just in case though.

Comment: @Zephyr Updated answer.

Comment: I get a `NullPointerException` on both `.lookup(".container")` and `.lookup(".graphic-container")`, @Slaw.

Comment: @Zephyr What version of Java are you using?

Comment: This project is Java 8, specifically JDK 1.8.0.161

Comment: Excellent explaination. I just changed to using the included `DialogPane` instead, but also setting the `DialogPane` to my own before `applyCss()` worked as well. Thank you!